# Bulleted/numbered list should recognise multiple items separated by new line

Tags: feature-request, bug, markdown, editor, list

I've got the following list separated by new line characters (without bullet points yet):

```
aa
bb
cc
dd
ee
```

now I'm selecting these 5 lines and applying *Bulleted List* option in editor. This is what I've got:

```
- aa bb cc dd ee
```

I think *Bulleted List* and *Numbered List* should recognise new lines and create list with 5 items, not 1. This is especially trouble for longer lists.